# How do I resolve "Use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment instead"

Tags: python

I am using python script for people detection. 
I have the following line in my script:

```
import time
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path
from imutils.video import FPS
from collections import deque
from sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_ import linear_assignment
```

When I run my script I have got the following lines:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/linear_assignment_.py:127:
     DeprecationWarning: The linear_assignment function is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed from 0.23. Use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment instead.
     DeprecationWarning)
```

Please, advice me how to solve it.

Answer (score 22):

You need to replace the `sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_.linear_assignment` function by the `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment function`.

The difference is in the return format: `linear_assignment()` is returning a *numpy array* and `linear_sum_assignment()` a *tuple of numpy arrays*. You obtain the same output by converting the output of linear_sum_assignment() in array and transpose it.

Your script should look like this:

```
import time
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path
from imutils.video import FPS
from collections import deque
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

#compute your cost matrix
indices = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)  
indices = np.asarray(indices)
indices = np.transpose(indices)
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the **linear_assignment** for **linear_sum_assignment**

```
# from sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_ import linear_assignment
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
cost = np.array([[4, 1, 3], [2, 0, 5], [3, 2, 2]])
# result = linear_assignment(cost)
result = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
result = np.array(list(zip(*result)))
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html