# No module named 'sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a [project from github](https://github.com/cfotache/pytorch_objectdetecttrack) , every object counter applications using sort algorithm. I can't run any of them because of a specific error, attaching errors screenshot. Can anyone help me about fixing this issue?
[image]

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Additionally, this is a `scikit-learn` question, and it has nothing to do with `deep-learning`, `yolo`, or `object-detection` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited)

Comment: I faced it when i going inside of **deep learning** and **yolo**. So how can i know exactly.

Comment: From the fact that you don't *show* anything related to these models/technlogies - just an import issue of a specific package.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `linear_assignment` function is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed from 0.23, but `sklearn.utils.linear_assignment_` can be replaced by `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`.

You can use:

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment as linear_assignment
```

then you can run the file and don't need to change the code.

Comment: Note this point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57992848/9328993

Answer (score 19):

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2
```

Comment: pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2 --upgrade   --> might be useful for the ones who had installed the newer version before.

Comment: Have faced with this issue with Deep Sort python implementation with scikit-learn 0.24 version, you saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

As **yiakwy** points out in a [github comment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13464#issuecomment-596901940) the `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` **is not** the perfect replacement:

> I am concerned that linear_sum_assignment is not equivalent to linear_assignment which later implements "maximum values" matching strategy not "complete matching" strategy, i.e. in tracking problem maybe an old landmark lost and a new detection coming in. We don't have to make a complete assignment, just match as more as possible.

I have found this out while trying to use it inside SORT-based yolo tracking code which that replacement broke (I was lucky that it did otherwise, I would get wrong results from the experiments without realising it...)

Instead, I suggest copying the module itself to the last version of sklearn and include as module in your code.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.X/sklearn/utils/linear_assignment_.py

For instance if you copy this file into an `utils` directory import with `from utils.linear_assignment_ import linear_assignment`

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `pip` to install `lap` and optionally `scipy`;
2. Uncomment the import and use the following function:

```py
def linear_assignment(cost_matrix):
  try:
    import lap
    _, x, y = lap.lapjv(cost_matrix, extend_cost=True)
    return np.array([[y[i], i] for i in x if i >= 0])
  except ImportError:
    from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
    x, y = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
    return np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
```

Answer (score -4):

You are getting this error because you haven't install scikit module yet.
Install scikit-learn module from https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/

Comment: I did already.
pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: threadpoolctl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy

Comment: @FurkanEraslan There does not seem to be such a module in the current scikit-learn version: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils