# ValueError: too many values to unpack using sum return function

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

Attempting to implement [this Deep Embedded Clustering](https://github.com/CharlesNord/DEC-pytorch) GitHub algorithm.

```
    def acc(y_pred, y_target):
        D = max(y_pred.max(), y_target.max()) + 1
        w = np.zeros((D, D), dtype=np.int64)
        for i in range(y_pred.size):
            w[y_pred[i], y_target[i]] += 1

        ind = linear_assignment(w.max() - w)
        return sum(w[i, j] for i, j in ind) * 1.0 / y_pred.size # <- Error Line
```

Just using the code within the repo I am encountering this ValueError. I attempted to use the zip function to solve this as well as assigning the output to a variable before passing return.

Comment: Apparently, `ind` doesn't iterate over tuples of two elements `(i, j)` for some reason

Comment: You need to inspect `ind` then figure out how it went awry. ... [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391260/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391260/2823755) might be of interest.

Comment: Maybe you need `... for i, j in zip(ind))` - the *new* `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` returns a `[row_indices, col_indices]` array.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if anyone else encounters similar issue. The Github Repo using `linear_assignment`  is deprecated and removed from updated scikit learn packages.

I had used the solution accepted as the answer within this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390517/no-module-named-sklearn-utils-linear-assignment/62391260#62391260) , However, as mentioned in that thread `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` is not the perfect replacement for linear assignment. This was causing my issue as the output of the two functions is different.

Two options is you can downgrade your Scikit learn package to the version which supports `linear assignment`, or comment out the import and use the old function definition as posted by **InputBlackBoxOutput** in linked thread, and below.

```
def linear_assignment(cost_matrix):
  try:
    import lap
    _, x, y = lap.lapjv(cost_matrix, extend_cost=True)
    return np.array([[y[i], i] for i in x if i >= 0])
  except ImportError:
    from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
    x, y = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
    return np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
```